# Does IE 7 and 8 use Internet explorer event model?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I am reading "Javascript The Definitive Guide". In this book, Events and Event handling, there are three event-handling models, the original event model, the standard event model and Internet explorer event model.

It says upto IE6 it uses Internet explorer event model.

I am wondering if IE7 and 8 still uses it.
Or does it use the standard event model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internet Explorer 7 and 8 continue to stick with the Microsoft  event model from IE6, and do not use the W3C event model.

Comment: Oh dear oh dear MS ! :-(
Thanks Daniel.